# iOS app crashes randomly in WebCore

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have an iPad app that has UIWebview and it loads an URL. Problem is it crashes randomly and doesnt provide much info. I am using ARC.

Any thoughts please?

Thanks

image 1[image]

image 2[image]

image 3[image]

Comment: Its an enterprise app, its made on JQUERY. URL is not accessible outside of the network.

Comment: Ok... what I am really after is the html source. I want to see if it is reproducible outside of your app, ie in a plain webview.

Comment: is it possible that html can cause the crash? Problem is it doesnt crash all the time. It crashes randomly. If you use the app for some time continuously you will see the crash.

Comment: You have to make sure to set the UIWebView's delegate to nil whenever you remove an UIWebView from your view - that may cause random crashes otherwise.

Comment: UIWebView is always there. i am not removing it and i have also set the delegate to nil but still having the problem.

Comment: This issue got fixed, in CSS there was a reference of an image but image was not there. iOS code was fine.
Thanks for help

Comment: Glad you fixed your specific problem (seriously) but this isn't a happy ending: CSS code, no matter how bogus, should not wreck the UIWebView/browser and the application with it... This problem (as many other) seem to have been introduced in iOs > 7.0 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196235/uiwebview-webcore-crashes-in-ios7-1-example-www-latimes-com), if someone has some more information on this regard I'd welcome to post them...

Comment: (PS: without taking nothing from what I said, finding some incorrectly referenced CSS images fixed my problem too, so +1)