# UIWebView webCore crashes in iOS7.1 (example: www.latimes.com)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, ios7

I have being seeing crashes in my iOS app, when opening LA Times (www.latimes.com). The crash happens in WebCore somewhere and I have no clue where. Profiling with both "Zombie" or "leaks" do not return anything for this "EXE_BAD_ADDRESS" error.

I also checked with a small, bare UIWebView app and I could reproduce the effects.

Right now, I see this happening only with LA times, but I am not sure if there are other sites as well.

Can someone check on and guide me in what could be the possible error/source for this crash?

**EDIT:** I have added a small UIWebView project demonstrating this bug at
[github](https://github.com/nikhiljjoshi/iosCrash)

**EDIT 2:** The app (include the demo at github) works perfectly fine on iOS 7.0, but crashes in iOS 7.1 ... seems a recent bug with iOS 7.1. I have issued a bug report to Apple and will keep updated.
Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: @Larme, I guess you are asking for the stack trace. Other than that I don't observe anything :(.

Comment: Loaded fine. Upload a sample project, add the device specs.

Comment: @A-Live, do they allow for uploading on SO somewhere? Or the usual github?

Comment: You can only add a link here.

Comment: @A-Live, added a link to github repo. in the question.

Comment: Stil loaded fine, both general and "special for tablets blahblahblah" versions. Please add your device specs. I was using iPad 3 with iOs 7.0.4 (11B554a). Try disabling any accessibility settings, change locale to US and other regional parameters to something generic, see if it makes any difference. Oh, and try another internet connection.

Comment: @A-Live, ohh so you mean, the project on github could work well on your side? This leaves for only one possibility: I have iOS 7.1 (11D5099e) on my iPad mini. 
Also I have checked on two other iPads (iPad 2 and iPad air) running the same OS.

Comment: @A-Live, BTW the same build works well on iOS6.

Comment: @A-Live, okay... I checked on my side. The site works well with iOS 7.0... so the problem is with iOS 7.1 in particular.... updated the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524325/where-can-i-learn-more-about-webcoresharedbufferdata http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112838/webcoresharedbufferdata-getbytesrange-range-0-8-exceeds-data-length-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812205/uiwebview-crash-on-webcore?rq=1 some have traces

Comment: You can use [Apple bug reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/), that or a paid support ticket are probably the only ways to get some Apple engineers on the issue and I'm afraid the others won't be able to help you.

Comment: @A-Live, thanks for the reference. I have already posted a ticket three days back. I haven't received any response yet though. I will update!

Answer (score 0):

I happened to bump into that same issue with one of my apps in iOS>7.0 only.

It seems to be a sync issue which can be fixed by creating the webview from the main thread only.

As a fix I just wrapped my `UIWebView` creation in a `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });`

And it solved the problem.
Of course if your code is running on the main thread you shouldn't wrap it this way ;)